# OpenVPN Client Local LAN Access

Tags: openvpn

I have setup OpenVPN on Win2K12R2 on AWS. I want MyOffice LAN network to be accessible from MyHome PC.

[See the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaAYc.png)

Client Subnet - 10.8.0.0/24
MyHome Subnet - 192.168.1.0/24
MyOffice Subnet - 192.168.2.0/24

I will connect from MyHome to OpenVPN Server and also connect MyOffice to OpenVPN Server. Once this connection is successful i want to communicate with other devices in MyOffice LAN from MyHome.

**Both Client Config**

client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/ca.crt"
cert "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/client-Myxxxx.crt"
key "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/client-Myxxxx.key"
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
mute 20

**Server Config**

port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/ca.crt"
cert "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/server.crt"
key "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/server.key" 
dh "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/keys/dh2048.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir ccd
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
;duplicate-cn
persist-key
persist-tun

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure your office PC has a static vpn 10.8.0.x IP (use ccd directory for this, although generally pool persist should be ok).

You have to allow IP forwarding on your office PC (depends on OS how you do that).

Then create a route for 192.168.2.0/24 that has your office PC VPN IP as gateway (not you VPN server!)

client-to-client is enabled so you should ok

Edit:

Create a file in your ccd directory having name of your office pc client name

In this file add this line:

```
iroute 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

You can see more info about this on the following page

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response. Yes MyOffice PC have static IP 10.8.0.8 and MyHome PC have 10.8.0.6.

I have already enabled IP Forwarding from registry on both machines, both are Windows.

Where do i have to create a route for 192.168.2.0/24 GW 10.8.0.8 ?

Yes, client-to-client is enabled.

Kindly Suggest

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Hi, When i have edited the push route as per above i get message "Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up..." and at last "MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1497793023,CONNECTED,ERROR,10.8.0.6,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1194,,".  Tunnel Comes up but when i route print there is no route for 192.168.2.0/24 network.

Comment: I edited my answer again to explain another solution. (remove the office IP from your push route that I suggested on the previous answer)

Comment: Hi, Yes i had did the same and it was not working earlier. May be due to the file had .txt in extension. Later i removed extension of the file and its working now. However i still have push route in place. I also see very high latency almost 600ms. I have very high bandwidth at all the nodes. Is it due to encryption in place ?

Comment: Nice you got it working! About high latency, check your CPU usage to see if it is high. You can also try to enable compression by adding comp-lzo on both your client and server configs but most times this makes things worse. There are info about performance on openvpn wiki but are mostly about linux. Take a look, you might find something useful for your case. https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN_Speed

Comment: Hi again, i tired the compression but no luck. Ping to OpenVPN Server Public IP is 250ms, Ping to OpenVPN VPN IP 10.8.0.1 from 10.8.0.6 is 250ms, Ping to OpenVPN VPN IP 10.8.0.1 from 10.8.0.8 is 250ms. But ping between clients 10.8.0.6 - 10.8.0.8 is 500ms. This is making me crazy.

Comment: This seems right. Ping from server to each client is 250ms. Ping between clients is twice this time so 500ms is expected since all traffic goes through the vpn server! Do not let client-to-client directive mislead you. It just says that the server allows VPN clients to see each other. But all traffic goes through the server. Perhaps you could setup a VPN server on some other location closer to your clients.

Comment: Great, i completelt agree with you and understood the scenario. Final words before we end our discussion, do you recommend me to move to Linux Server instead of Windows for OpenVPN Server? Does Linux improves the communication?

Comment: Glad I helped! Personally I have only used Linux for openvpn server so I cannot compare performance. You can try with a small Linux VPS and see what happens.